# How to Pass Multiple values from a request response into the body of a post request on soapui

Tags: soapui

This is my get request api
/api/pmswebservice/getEdata which gives me a JSON response

```
{
  "packet":{
     "header":{
         "responsecode":200,
         "responseMessege": "successful"
         "totalRecordCount": 3
       },
    "body":[
     {
        "value":196,
        "text": "abc"
     },
     {
        "value":197,
        "text":"bcd"
     },
     {
        "value":198,
        "text":"fgh"
     }],
 "totalRecordCount":3
}
}
```

Now I want to transfer the value 196,197,198 to a request body of post API
The request body looks like

```
{
  "divisionList":[
      196,197,198 ]
}
```

Currently I can transfer single data using property transfer and JSONPath

```
SOURCE: $.packet.body[0].value 
TARGET: $.divisionList[0]
```

Any IDEA on how to transfer multiple values to an array of JSON request

Answer (score 0):

Use Groovy Script.

One of the solutions:

1. In Groovy Script get JSON response.
2. Loop through *$.packet.body* array.
3. Save all retrieved values to test case property.
4. In request body use [property expansion](https://www.soapui.org/docs/scripting-and-properties/property-expansion/) to inject values from test case property.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response it worked

Comment: Great. If this answer has helped you solve your problem, you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).